# Bottlepy: template not found

Tags: python, bottle

I have server running on apache. I use bottle.py. When I'm going to xxx/getbio, SOMETIMES it returns :

`Error: 500 Internal Server Error: Template 'bio' not found.`

This error occurs not all time: if I restart apache, it's normalizing for several hours, but happens again. Here is code fragment :

```
@route('/getbio')
def getBio():
    return template('bio')
```

Here is file structure :

```
xxx/
├── views/
│   ├── bio.tpl
└── index.py
```

And I didin't missed following lines of code:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append('views')
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Please help me, because I don't have idea how to fix this bug

Comment: Can you post the details about how you integrate apache and bottle. Your config file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add your template location to `TEMPLATE_DIR`, not to `sys.path`:

```
bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, 'views')
```

---

You may find that it's more robust to use the absolute path:

```
bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, '/path/to/xxx/views')
```

Comment: How come relative paths don't work (as robustly) when Bottle itself is using those?

Comment: Because, unlike relative paths, absolute paths are not sensitive to external state (I.e., the current working directory of the process).

Answer (score 5):

By default Bottle adds the `views` folder to the template path for template files. However, at least on Windows, it looks for the views folder relative to where the python script was *invoked from* (ie. the current working directory) and *not* relative to where the app entry point `.py` file is found.

Therefore if your folder structure looks like this:

```
xxx/
├── views/
│   ├── bio.tpl
└── index.py
```

and `index.py` is your Bottle app entry point, you would need to launch `index.py` with `xxx` as the current working directory.

Hard-coding the path to the templates folder should work, but is not a portable solution.

You can however specify the absolute path to the templates folder in a portable way by determining it at *runtime* with code like this:

```
import os     
abs_app_dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
abs_views_path = os.path.join(abs_app_dir_path, 'views')
bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, abs_views_path )
```

Just change the line performing the `os.path.join` call to correctly construct the `abs_views_path` relative to your file.

This way, you can simply move the code from machine to machine, and run it from any working directory, and as long as your views folder location is always in the correct place *relative to your app* it will be found.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why an absolute path seems indeed required.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, bottle has `TEMPLATE_PATH` constant to store template paths. Try to modify it in the case you want e.g:

```
from pathlib import Path
from bottle import TEMPLATE_PATH

TEMPLATE_PATH.append(str(Path('path') / 'to' / 'template'))
```

Then, `path/to/template` path will be included as one of template paths in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Bottle have a bag in include () function

```
% include ("my_template.tpl")  # template not found
% include("my_template.tpl")  # template found
```

the only difference it is space after "include" is forbidden.

Hope this issue message will help somebody save time in debugging
https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/issues/1258

And template have to be in bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH
bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, abs_views_path )

Answer (score -1):

If you only pass one keyword argument to the template() function, it will be interpreted as the name of the template file. Example:

```
return template('<h3>Hello World!</h3>')
```

If you do not have a template file with the name of `'<h3>Hello World!</h3>'`, you will get a `template not found` error.

Adding a substitution in the string, and keyword argument to the same line of code will cause Bottle to try and render the first argument as the template itself, instead of searching for it as a file.

```
return template('<h3>Hello, {{foobar}}</h3>', foobar='foobar')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right. If you say `bottle.template('just one string argument')`, then there's nowhere to put the actual template parameters. Also, `bottle.template('somefile.tpl', foobar='foobar')` will indeed look for a file.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I don't understand why I would be downvoted. My code works as posted, look at the documentation at https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html

Comment: Your answer said "Adding a keyword argument" made the difference, but a moment's testing shows that that's not true. What seems to make the difference is whether the first argument contains any substitutions. `template('Hello world')` searches for a file named "Hello world"; `template('Hello {{world}}')` treats the string as a literal template and complains about the lack of any `world` kwarg. Besides which, your answer doesn't actually help the OP solve their problem, whereas the other two answers actually do help solve the problem.

Comment: Point taken on the technicality of the keyword argument, I slightly edited my answer but my goal was to give more insight into how the template `function` operates.